# How to include a php file depending on what the user select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have lot of divs, may be a dozen or two, like...

```
<div class="mydivs" id="firstdiv"></div>
<div class="mydivs" id="seconddiv"></div>
<div class="mydivs" id="thirddiv"></div>
<div class="mydivs" id="forthdiv"></div>
<div class="mydivs" id="fifthdiv"></div>
```

and so on

when the user click on any of those divs, i want to load unique php files with name like (this.id).php into those divs.

```
$(".mydivs").click(function(){
    $(this).html("<?php include " + this.id + ".php ?>");
});
```

How is this possible?

Comment: You need to use AJAX to do that

Comment: Could you explain how?

Comment: PHP is server side, javascript is client side. By the time you get to javascript, the PHP for the page has already been loaded by the server and delivered. So, I'm guessing you want those includes on another page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery, you can do something like

```
$(".mydivs").click(function() {
    var that = this;
    $.get(this.id + ".php", function(data, status) {
        $(that).html(data);
    };
});
```

It's async, so you might also want a small spinner or something to show that something is loading.

This also will eliminate any security issues. For example, if the code today was reading from user input, such as `getFile.php?file=1.php`, then you'll run into problems. The current code above will simply return a 404 if the file doesn't exist. And it's not `including`, it's just getting the page with AJAX, which a browser could do without this code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure this is safe to do. You shouldn't use user input to select the file for PHP `include`. Users' requests are easily manipulated - they could include a script that you don't want them to or, if the server is not configured properly, include their own PHP file with malicious code.

If you just want to load some other page, use AJAX instead and always check if the requested resource is something that you want the user to see.